# Is it correct to use revert this way?

Tags: solidity

I have an abstract contract and I need to validate the parameters and return an error if not valid and also return the gas fees.

I created a modifier called `checkNumber` and inside I validate the _number and use require and revert.

**CODE**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

// Solidity files have to start with this pragma.
// It will be used by the Solidity compiler to validate its version.
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

struct Information {
    uint number;
    string avatar;
}

abstract contract AbstractCandidate {
    uint[6] private _numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    string[6] private _avatars = [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-1.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-2.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-3.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-4.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-5.png",
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagosaud/dApp-superior-electoral-court/main/temp/imgs/candidate-6.png"
    ];

    modifier checkNumber(uint _number) {
        string memory _errorMessage = "Candidate number is incorret!";

        require(_number < 1 || _number > _numbers.length, _errorMessage);

        if (_number < 1 || _number > _numbers.length) {
            revert(_errorMessage);
        }

        _;
    }

    function getInformation(uint _number) external view checkNumber(_number) returns(Information memory) {
        return Information({ avatar: _avatars[_number], number: _numbers[_number] });
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but is unnecessary. Failing `require` will fail the transaction.

Comment: So do Require and Assert return the gas value equally to revert? Why is there revert then? @OFRBG

Answer (score 1):

According to this logic you will always get _errorMessage. For example in require statement if _number 0 you wont get err, but youll get it in if statement, because 0 < 1 and it fits to your if statement condition.